# react router routing with parameter id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with passing parameters inside the route.
Currently, I have these routes:

```
<Route component={CategoriesPage} path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}`} exact/>
<Route component={CoursesPage} path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:id`} exact/>
<Route component={SectionPage} path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:id/:id`} exact/>
```

So SectionPage route will look like this: courses/k-8-grades/early-math

**What I want to do**:

- When the section page reached add a new id parameter. Video lesson id.
  So it should be: courses/k-8-grades/early-math/videoId
- When clicking button overview. Add url #overview. So it should be courses/k-8-grades/early-math/videoId#overview.
- When clicking button search. Remove url #overview add #search. So it would be courses/k-8-grades/early-math/videoId#search

**So what I tried:**

- Using redirects. When reached SectionPage somehow pass id to redirect. But it failed because routes didn't match properly.

```
<Redirect from={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:id/:id/`} to={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:id/:id/test`} />
 {/* courses/early-math/early-math/test */}
<Route component={SectionPage} path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:id/:id/`} exact/>
{/* courses/k-8-grades/early-math */}
```

- In Section Page add lesson id onInit. But if I manually add it

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const history = useHistory();
history.push('fdfdf');
```

When it would become **courses/k-8-grades/fdfdf** instead of **courses/k-8-grades/early-math/fdfdf**

**Update**
So what I came up with doing is creating a SectionRedirect page:

```
<Route component={CategoriesPage} path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}`} exact />
<Route component={CoursesPage} path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:a`} exact />
<Route component={SectionRedirectPage} path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:a/:b/`} exact />
<Route component={SectionPage} path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:a/:b/:id`} exact />
```

Section redirect page pushes videoID. Because I need to pathname before fetching correct video id courses/k-8-grades/early-math.

```
props.history.push(`${location.pathname}/${videoId}`);
```

In section page, I used like suggested and it worked wonders.

```
props.history.push({ hash: "overview" })
```

Unfortunately, it didn't fully solve my problem:
Expected behavior:
Currently when visiting section Page my url is this:

```
courses/k-8-grades/early-math/videoId1#overview
```

Clicking on second video link should change url to this:

```
courses/k-8-grades/early-math/videoId2#overview
```

Real life example would be udemy video player.

Found solution using:
In section.page

```
history.push({
      pathname: '/courses/k-8-grades/early-math/videoId'
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you refer to both of the two variable parts of your path with `:id`.

You are trying to map `courses/k-8-grades/early-math/` to `courses/:id/:id/`.

Instead I think you should map it to something of the form: `courses/:a/:b/`.

For adding `#overview` or `#search` to the path you could do this:

```
history.push({ hash: "overview" })
```

Example implementation:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          component={CategoriesPage}
          path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}`}
          exact
        />
        <Route
          component={CoursesPage}
          path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:id`}
          exact
        />
        <Redirect
          exact
          from={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:a/:b/`}
          to={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:a/:b/videoId`}
        />
        <Route
          component={SectionPage}
          exact
          path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:a/:b/videoId`}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

function SectionPage() {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => history.push({ hash: "overview" })}>
        overview
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => history.push({ hash: "search" })}>search</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Example as sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-sea-n96jx?file=/src/App.js:982-993)

Comment: That's a good solution. However, it didn't fully solve my problem. Could you take a look at the updated question?

Comment: Finally, I think I solved it. Just need to test it.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is that you are trying to make two level deep nested routes from the same parent.

To solve the problem, go to your `<CoursesPage/>` and create a new `<Route/>` [using the useRouteMatch hook in this link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch). With this, you now have access to `<Route />` just as you had in `CategoriesPage`

```
 <Route component={CategoriesPage} path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}`} exact/>
 <Route component={CoursesPage} path={`/${AllRoutesEnum.COURSES}/:id`} exact/>
//remove the SectionPage page route
```

Go to `<CoursesPage/>` component to access the component `<Route />`

```
const CoursesPage = () =>{
let {path} = useRouteMatch()

return(
    <div>
        {/* Your desired Links */}
          <Switch>
            <Route path={`${path}`}>
                <div>We are here on CoursesPage</div>
            </Route>
            <Route path={`${path}/:videoId`}>
                <VideoId/>
            </Route>
            <Route path={`${path}/:videoId#overview`}>
                <VideoIdOverView/>
            </Route>
            <Route path={`${path}/:videoId#search`}>
                <VideoIdSearch/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
   
)}
```

Now you can now use your individual nested routes above such as:

```
const VideoId = () =>{
let { videoId } = useParams(); //make the destructured property name same with paths declared above
return (
    <div>
        {videoId}
    </div>
)}
```